# Missing dll File When Programming Hololens 2 in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, qr-code, hololens

I am trying to use Unity to track QR codes with the hololens 2. I have installed the Microsoft.MixedReality.QR plugin and I think it is installed correctly, though I am not super familiar with using packages in unity. When unity compiles, it gives me an error for the following line of code:
`[SerializeField] QRCodeWatcher qrTracker = new QRCodeWatcher();`

The first part of the error message looks like this (I cut out most of it because it is really long):

FileNotFoundException: Failed to load "vcruntime140_app.dll". Please ensure that "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable" is installed.

When I checked Control Panel, it says that "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64)" is installed. I found the "vcruntime140_app.dll" installed under the directory "C:\Windows\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_[a bunch of letters]"

What is wrong here? Am I missing something? It seems like everything is installed. Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your development environment? Here’s a recommended development environment:

- A Windows 10 or 11 PC
- Visual Studio 2022 with the required workloads
- Windows 10 SDK 10.0.18362.0 or later
- Unity Hub with Unity 2021.3 LTS installed

For more details, you can check - [Install the tools - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/install-the-tools?tabs=unity).

Based on the error message you provided, you can also refer to [VCRUNTIME140.dll Missing how can i fix - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/vcruntime140dll-missing-how-can-i-fix/c5c1461a-3b75-428c-9c5d-18d56a11f2bc).

Comment: I meet all of those requirements with the exception that I am using 2021.3.33f1. I will look into the error message link you sent me. Thank you for the help.